# Diffusion law for continuous domains

Tags: fluid-dynamics, diffusion

I'm an engineer, so don't expect too much :)

I'm modelling with FEM the convection-diffusion-reaction equation which is derived by the continuity equation.

$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} +\nabla \cdot j = R$

$c$ - scalar quantity like concentration

$R$ - source term

The flux $j$ is splitted in an additive manner into an advectivon and diffusion flux

$j = j_{diff}+j_{adv}=-D\nabla c+\mathbf{v}\cdot c$

$D$ - Diffusion matrix/coefficient

$\mathbf{v}$ - velocity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation#Derivation

As far as I understood the $j_{diff}$ term is obtained by using Fick's first law? Since this is a linear relationship I'm wondering if there are nonlinear laws which describe the macroscopic level. In case I couldn't express well what I exactly mean, feel free to ask, then I try to correct myself accordingly.

Best,

Max

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE. I think it might help if you could explain clearly what $c$, $j$, $R$ and $D$ are, and perhaps provide a link or reference for where that first equation comes from.

Comment: Hey @Time4Tea, I've edited the post

Comment: Sorry but, what's the question then? Are you asking for higher order diffusion formulae?

Comment: "First, diffusive flux arises due to diffusion. This is typically **approximated** by Fick's first law" - Wiki page from the post.


I'm wondering about the word approximated, this implies that there may be different laws to approximate the diffusive term in a more sophisticated way?

Comment: So ye kind of higher order diffusion formulae

Comment: For dilute solutions of solvent, Fick's law is typically adequate, although D  can be a function of temperature.  Other non-linearities can be present, however, from the kinetics term.  For higher concentrations, the transport behavior is more complicated.  For details, see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.

Comment: Hey @ChesterMiller thanks for the book suggestion. The domain I'm modelling is a bit more complex but I tried to approximate it first with some artificial fluid. However, it includes more phases and is basically a heterogeneous catalysis. The book got a dedicated chapter for this, so maybe this helps me :)